# Iterate elements and toggle using classList in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, dom-manipulation

Conditions:

1. Please use javascript and `classList` property to invert which elements have `.highlight` class.
2. Basically iterate over all the `<li>` elements and toggle the class of `.highlight`.
   on each one.
3. You should not alter anything in HTML and CSS.

[Your result should be like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysBR7.png)

```js
/* app.js */
let list =  document.querySelector('li');

list.classList.add('');
```

```css
/* index.css */
/*No need to touch anything in this file:*/
li {
  background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #7FDBFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>ClasList</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <!--LEAVE THIS FILE ALONE!-->
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution removes the `.highlight` class style from the `<li>` if the `.highlight` class style is applied to the `<li>`. If the `.highlight` class style is not applied to the `<li>` element, the `.highlight` class style is added to the `<li>` element.

###### Method-1

```js
/* The querySelectorAll() method is used to select all <li> elements. */
let list = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var listArray = [...list];

/* Each <li> element is checked using the forEach() method. */
listArray.forEach(element => {
  /* Is the ".highlight" class style applied to the <li> element? */
  if(element.classList.contains("highlight")) {
    /* Remove the ".highlight" class style from the <li> element. */
    element.classList.remove("highlight");
  }
  else {
    /* Add the class style ".highlight" to the <li> element. */
    element.classList.add("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #7FDBFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>ClasList</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

###### Method-2

```js
/* The querySelectorAll() method is used to select all <li> elements. */
let list = document.querySelectorAll('li');

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < list.length ; ++i) {
    if(list[i].classList.contains("highlight")) 
      list[i].classList.remove("highlight");
    else 
      list[i].classList.add("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #7FDBFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>ClasList</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works pretty fine dude! But still, if can you give another logic by using loops?

Comment: @vasanthn I updated my answer. You can check out Method-2.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* The querySelectorAll() method is used to select all <li> elements. */

const li= document.querySelectorAll('li');

for(let i of li) {
    i.classList.toggle("highlight");
}
```

```css
li {
  background-color: #B10DC9;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #7FDBFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>ClasList</title>
 
    <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li class="highlight">Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

/*Below is the js !!!*/

```
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let li of lists ){
  if (li.classList.contains('highlight')) {
    li.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
  else{
    li.classList.add('highlight');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

li.forEach(element => element.classList.toggle('highlight'));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.